# how to switch off update button in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In `R`'s `shiny` I want to create an app that includes a function to operate on values given by the user and return the result (the input data as well). I rewrote some examples found on the net and came up with:

```
library(shiny)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    values <- reactiveValues()
    values$df <- data.frame(N = numeric(0), A = numeric(0), C = numeric(0))

    newEntry <- observe({

      if(input$update > 0) {
        gr <- 10 + input$n
        newLine <- isolate(c(input$n, input$nr1, gr))
        isolate(values$df[nrow(values$df) + 1,] <- c(input$n, input$nr1, gr))
              }
    })

    output$table1 <- renderTable({values$df})

})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("submitButton example"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, wellPanel(
      sliderInput("nr1", "Give a number: ",  min = 0, max = 100, value = 0, step = 2),

      sliderInput("n", "N:", min = 10, max = 1000, value = 200,
                  step = 10),

      actionButton("update", "Update Table")

    )),
    column(6,
           tableOutput("table1")    
    )
  )
))
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is almost what I want with the exception that after the first click on the `Update Table` button the app updates the table values without waiting for the next click. How to cope with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- data.frame(N = numeric(0), A = numeric(0), C = numeric(0))

  newEntry <- observeEvent(input$update,{
    gr <- 10 + input$n
    values$df[nrow(values$df) + 1,] <- c(input$n, input$nr1, gr)
  })
  output$table1 <- renderTable({values$df})
})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("submitButton example"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, wellPanel(
      sliderInput("nr1", "Give a number: ",  min = 0, max = 100, value = 0, step = 2),
      sliderInput("n", "N:", min = 10, max = 1000, value = 200, step = 10),
      actionButton("update", "Update Table"))),
    column(6, tableOutput("table1"))
  )
))
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: this is what I have been looking for

Comment: I don't think you need the `isolate` within `observeEvent`